# Standalone NFC/RFID with WiFi/ethernet network connection

Tags: smart-home, hardware, wireless, rfid, nfc

I spent many hours looking for a device for my iot project. So far, everything I find does not meet my expectations. I prepared two prototypes - one based on rpi zero and one based on esp32, but I need something from mass production for my customers which includes the required EU / RoHS certifications and is retailable by them. I also need an SDK for this device to be able to upload my software.

The required setup for the device

- standalone, no mobile or pc connection required for work
- able to connect to network via wifi or ethernet, sends http request and handle responses
- has built-in nfc/reader which may work with mobile android mobile apps and 13.56MHz rfid cards/tags
- has buil-in lcd (prefered somthing like hd44780 16x2 characters)
- internal sd card storage
- support a Bluetooth connection or be able to turn into an access point for configuration via a mobile app

For now I found device like:

- Orbit IP
- µFR Nano Online
- Famoco FX100
- RDM560

but each of them has their own deficiencies.

Maybe there is someone who know this kind of device which is easy to buy, program and resale in EU? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure they meet **all** of your requirements, but they may be starting points:

- [QBIC TD-0350](https://www.qbictechnology.com/td-0350)
- [Embrava Desk Sign](https://emea.embrava.com/products/desk-sign)
- [Condeco Desk Booking Screen](https://www.condecosoftware.com/products/desk-booking/desk-booking-screens/)

Some may only be available as part of a complete service.

Comment: @jcaron why are you answering a shopping question?